# Copy files from one Azure VM to another with a file watch

Tags: azure, file-copying

I'm trying to set up a situation where I drop files into a folder on one Azure VM, and they're automatically copied to another Azure VM. I was thinking about mapping a drive from the receiver to the sender and using a file watch/copy program to send the files over the mapped drive.

What's a good recommendation for a file watch/copy program that's simple and efficient, and what security setups do I need to get the two Azure boxes to "talk" to each other? They're in the same account/resource group/etc, so I'm not going outside of a virtual network or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VMs in the same virtual network can talk to each other (this is true even if default NSGs are applied).  So you wouldn't have to do anything special to get that type of communication working.

To answer the second part, you might want to consider just using built-in FCI rules to execute a short script to do the copy.  See [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758756(WS.10).aspx) for a short intro into FCI rules.

Alternatively, you could use a service such as [Azure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/File-Service-Concepts) to have files shared between those servers using CIFS.  It really depends on why you are trying to have a copy of the file on two servers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Windows VMs? Might also consider DFS or DSC - it depends a bit on what/why you're trying to accomplish this...

Comment: @bmoore-msft you are correct, the question is fairly open ended. Storage spaces with replication would be a neat solution